# SExtractor parameters for identifying Star Forming regions

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, star-formation, photometry

I am using SExtractor (Source Extractor) to identify Star-Forming regions in a galaxy. The problem is I am unable to choose the parameters required for it. SExtractor is just a tool to identify the sources in a field. These can be point sources as well as extended diffuse sources. So it is not clear how to go about applying the sextractor and then isolating/identifying only the extended regions as the star-forming regions.  Basically, why and how to choose the extent of 'X' pixels?

I need to calculate the Petrosian radius for each source as well. I can draw a histogram of the Petrosian radii for all the sources detected within the PSF of the instrument and use only those sources that have a radius larger than a certain value (say the FWHM or PSF of a bright Point source in the field). I think the histogram will be skewed towards larger radii as there are a large number of SF regions in the image and then set the size, like say 'X' pixels. And then I could do the photometry on the identified SF regions.

How do I find the Petrosian radius and proceed with using the SExtractor? Could someone tell me the inputs for this? Here are the default parameters.

### Default configuration file for SExtractor 2.12.4

### EB 2010-10-10

### Catalog

CATALOG_NAME     FUV_BaF2_comp.txt      # name of the output catalog
CATALOG_TYPE     ASCII_HEAD     # NONE,ASCII,ASCII_HEAD, ASCII_SKYCAT,
# ASCII_VOTABLE, FITS_1.0 or FITS_LDAC
PARAMETERS_NAME  default.param  # name of the file containing catalog contents

### Extraction

DETECT_TYPE      CCD            # CCD (linear) or PHOTO (with gamma correction)
DETECT_MINAREA   15              # min. # of pixels above threshold

DETECT_THRESH    5            #  or , in mag.arcsec-2
ANALYSIS_THRESH  1.5            #  or , in mag.arcsec-2

FILTER           Y              # apply filter for detection (Y or N)?
FILTER_NAME      gauss_4.0_7x7.conv   # name of the file containing the filter

DEBLEND_NTHRESH  30             # Number of deblending sub-thresholds
DEBLEND_MINCONT  0.18          # Minimum contrast parameter for deblending

CLEAN            Y              # Clean spurious detections? (Y or N)?
CLEAN_PARAM      1.0            # Cleaning efficiency

### WEIGHTing

WEIGHT_TYPE      NONE           # type of WEIGHTing: NONE, BACKGROUND,
# MAP_RMS, MAP_VAR or MAP_WEIGHT
WEIGHT_IMAGE     weight.fits    # weight-map filename

### FLAGging

FLAG_IMAGE       flag.fits      # filename for an input FLAG-image
FLAG_TYPE        OR             # flag pixel combination: OR, AND, MIN, MAX
# or MOST

### Photometry

PHOT_APERTURES   5.0              # MAG_APER aperture diameter(s) in pixels
PHOT_AUTOPARAMS  2.5, 1.5       # MAG_AUTO parameters: <Kron_fact>,<min_radius>
PHOT_PETROPARAMS 2.0, 3.5       # MAG_PETRO parameters: <Petrosian_fact>,
# <min_radius>
PHOT_AUTOAPERS   0.0,0.0        # , minimum apertures
# for MAG_AUTO and MAG_PETRO

SATUR_LEVEL      55000.0        # level (in ADUs) at which arises saturation
SATUR_KEY        SATURATE       # keyword for saturation level (in ADUs)

MAG_ZEROPOINT    0.0            # magnitude zero-point
MAG_GAMMA        4.0            # gamma of emulsion (for photographic scans)
GAIN             1.00            # detector gain in e-/ADU
GAIN_KEY         GAIN           # keyword for detector gain in e-/ADU
PIXEL_SCALE      1.0            # size of pixel in arcsec (0=use FITS WCS info)

### Star/Galaxy Separation

SEEING_FWHM      1.5            # stellar FWHM in arcsec
STARNNW_NAME     default.nnw    # Neural-Network_Weight table filename

### Background

BACK_TYPE        AUTO           # AUTO or MANUAL
BACK_VALUE       0.0            # Default background value in MANUAL mode
BACK_SIZE        8             # Background mesh:  or ,
BACK_FILTERSIZE  5              # Background filter:  or ,

### Check Image

CHECKIMAGE_TYPE  BACKGROUND,-OBJECTS           # can be NONE, BACKGROUND, BACKGROUND_RMS,
# MINIBACKGROUND, MINIBACK_RMS, -BACKGROUND,
# FILTERED, OBJECTS, -OBJECTS, SEGMENTATION,
# or APERTURES
CHECKIMAGE_NAME  Background_FUV_BaF2_comp.fits, Subtracted_FUV_BaF2_comp.fits     # Filename for the check-image

### Memory (change with caution!)

MEMORY_OBJSTACK  3000           # number of objects in stack
MEMORY_PIXSTACK  300000         # number of pixels in stack
MEMORY_BUFSIZE   1024           # number of lines in buffer

### ASSOCiation

ASSOC_NAME       sky.list       # name of the ASCII file to ASSOCiate
ASSOC_DATA       2,3,4          # columns of the data to replicate (0=all)
ASSOC_PARAMS     2,3,4          # columns of xpos,ypos[,mag]
ASSOC_RADIUS     2.0            # cross-matching radius (pixels)
ASSOC_TYPE       NEAREST        # ASSOCiation method: FIRST, NEAREST, MEAN,
# MAG_MEAN, SUM, MAG_SUM, MIN or MAX
ASSOCSELEC_TYPE  MATCHED        # ASSOC selection type: ALL, MATCHED or -MATCHED

### Miscellaneous

VERBOSE_TYPE     NORMAL         # can be QUIET, NORMAL or FULL
HEADER_SUFFIX    .head          # Filename extension for additional headers
WRITE_XML        N              # Write XML file (Y/N)?
XML_NAME         sex.xml        # Filename for XML output
XSL_URL          file:///usr/local/share/sextractor/sextractor.xsl
# Filename for XSL style-sheet

Comment: Why have you chosen/do you think that Sextractor is the right tool for the job?

Comment: Could you suggest any other tool which can be used instead of this? I know only this, so I used this. My supervisor also suggested this. Kindly let me know if there is any other better tool.